# The Swift Folder is Empty - App Rejected

Tags: ios, swift, appcelerator

I have an application that has been rejected due to the Swift Folder being empty. I have complied using appcelerator and the folder is empty, from research and even appcelerator say that the problem is fixed in 6.0.1.GA. Now that support is no longer available with Indie package it makes it harder! Has anyone got the same problem or have a fix?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702415/ipa-file-structure-supportswift-symbols) looks helpful tou your case?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an Indie package, you'll need to stick with open source tools to download SDK's. Of course there is the [GitHub repository of Appcelerator](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile) where you can download the source and build from there. There also is the [builds page by Appcelerator](http://builds.appcelerator.com) where you can get the nightlies.

But in your case the best solution is the [TiSDK CLI tool](https://github.com/dbankier/tisdk). With this you can download SDK's without the need of a license. The CLI tool downloads the code and packages it for you.